# Expressjs route param as variable in main app

Tags: node.js, express

For my app I have two route set up,

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/:name', routes.index);
```

I would like it to be so that if I don't specify a param, say just go to appurl.com (localhost:3000), it would load a default user, but if I do specify a param(localhost:3000/user), use that as the variable "username" in the following function (placed after my routes).

```
(function getUser(){
    var body = '',
        username = 'WillsonSM',

    options = {
    host: 'ws.audioscrobbler.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/2.0/?method=user.gettopartists&user=' + username + '&format=json&limit=20&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE'
    };

        require('http').request(options, function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {

                body = JSON.parse(body);
                artists = body.topartists.artist;

            });

        }).end();

})();
```

Along with this I have my route set up like so:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'LasTube' });

  username = req.params.name;
  console.log(username);
};
```

unfortunately setting username there to `req.params.name` does not seem to be accessible from the main app function.

My question is: How can I set expressjs/nodejs to use the parameter set via /name when available, and just use a default - in this example "WillsonSM" if not available.

I've tried taking "username" out of the main app, and just leaving it in the function, but username becomes undefined, as it is inaccessible from the route, and the app will not run. I can spit out "username" via the routes console.log, so assigning it there is not an issue, but as I am new to expressjs, I am unaware of how I should go about doing this. I have tried all I can think of and find from looking around the internet.

Also, if there is a better way of doing this, or I am doing something wrong, please let me know. If I've left out any information, just throw in a comment and I'll try to address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the immediate function call to `getUser()` is truly "after" your routes, it will be called once at startup, before you've handled any requests. I'm guessing that you want to do that once to establish a default setting for `artist` that will be used if the user doesn't supply a name in their request.

If that's so, you need to rewrite `getUser()` to take a username and a callback as parameters, and call the callback with the value you're currently assigning to `artist`. At initialization, call it with whatever username you want to use as a default and a callback that just sets `artist`. Then split your routes the way bryanmac suggested, using `artist` in `home()` and making a call to `getUser()` in `getNamed()`.

Comment: Thank you! With a little fiddling around and learning a bit more I was able to figure it out from what you said. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to setup two different routes - one for root and one for name supplied?  Since it routes to two different functions, you can control setting the default via the default '/' route or getting the :name via the url passed in (:name becomes req.params.name).

```
app.get('/', routes.home);
app.get(':name', routes.getNamed);
```

routes:

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {
    username = "defaultUser";
    // etc...
};

exports.getNamed = function (req, res) {
    username = req.params.name;
    // etc...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to figure it out with yours, and ebohlman's answers.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure I understood your question.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('appurl.com');
});

app.get('/:name', routes.index);
```